# Multiple audio file upload

Tags: php

I am creating a small social networking website in which a user can upload music files with some descriptions. The description and file path should be stored in a database and the mp3 file should be stored in a separate folder I want a PHP script for this.

If any one knows it then please help me.

Comment: Aint you going to try yourself first..?

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery script Multiple upload is possible with this
Check this out [jQuery Ajax uploader plugin (with progress bar!)...](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/)
Let me add script is tremendiously manipulative...
Like if want **only audio files** to be uploaded this is the thing
**Note.-** It uses Flash to show progress bar